# Hardwiring code to display arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, driver, super

I want to hardwire specific values for an x and y point, length and width of a rectangle so that they can be added to an arrayList. I have 4 classes: Circle, Point, Shape and Driver.

Comment: Look at the parameters of the constructor of your rectangle class. It accepts a Point object and 2 double values.

Answer (score 1):

```
r1 = new Rectangle('0.5', '4.0', '4.5', '2.5');
```

thats not your Rectangle constructor... it needs:

```
Rectangle(Point point1, double length, double width)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply parameter types of the `Rectangle` class as expected by its constructor:

```
r1 = new Rectangle('0.5', '4.0', '4.5', '2.5');
```

should be

```
r1 = new Rectangle(new Point(0.5, 4.0), 4.5, 2.5);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Rectangle needs the arguments Point, double, double.  When you make r1 you should write:

```
r1 = new Rectangle(new Point(.5, 4.0), 4.5, 2.5);
```